iPhone 3g/3gs won't start unless it is charging through old adapter
I found my old 3g/3gs iPhone (I don't know if it's 3g or 3gs) and it only starts if it is charging thru an old iPhone adapter (the thing connected to the wall outlet). For some reason it requires me to connect with iTunes to start the device, but when slide the SOS call slider it shows my old wallpaper from many years ago.
Anyone know how to reactivate it? Or how to avoid having to reactivate it as it should already be activated?
How would i go by connecting it to itunes when it doesnt turn on without being connected to its specific adapter?

To identify iPhone type

Not sure but if not not used for a while  it may be in DFU mode. Have you an old Mac or PC with iTunes ?

i'll attempt connecting it to an old mac when i get the chance Ptit Xav
